# How to reduce duplication in java methods?

Tags: java, cucumber

I have to run my test cases in different environments and generate reports. I have separate config for each environment to store the urls, username and password and the path for my xl sheet where I put my test results along with screenshots. The problem is that for each task like loading the config files, taking screen shots, generating xl reports I have to the same method for each environment (QA, DEV, Production etc) with a different name Bellow is a few methods environment for the two of my environments — I have at least three more and I am basically copying and pasting the same code Just changing the names of the methods. How would you write these in a better way to be able to reuse the methods — I want to be able to have just one screenshot method and writeToExcel method and be able to use it across my framework. I am working on a cucumber-junit framework.

```
public class MainLibrary {

public static Webdriver driver;

public String loadQA_Properties(String property) throws IOException {

Properties p = new Properties();
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(“QA-property-file-path-goes-here”);
pr.load(input);
String propVal = p.getProperty(property);
return propVal;
}

  public String loadDev_Properties(String property) throws IOException {
      Properties p = new Properties();
      InputStream input = new FileInputStream(“Dev-property-file-path-goes-here”);
      pr.load(input);
      String propVal = p.getProperty(property);
      return propVal;
     }
 }
```

I have 3 more methods of the same type for different environments -- These methods gets called in my utility classes as following:

```
 public String screenshotQA(WebDriver driver, String ss_name) throws IOException {
      MainLibrary   obj = new  MainLibrary (driver);
      String path = obj.loadQA_Properties("screenshotPath") + ss_name + ".png";
      TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
      File src = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
      File destination = new File(path);
      FileHandler.copy(src, destination);
      return path;
    }
   public String screenshotDev(WebDriver driver, String ss_name) throws IOException {
       MainLibrary   obj = new  MainLibrary (driver);
       String path = obj.loadQA_Properties("screenshotPath") + ss_name + ".png";
       TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
       File src = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
       File destination = new File(path);
       FileHandler.copy(src, destination);
       return path;
     }
   //I am create the same method for all my environment, because of the loadproperty Methods

  public void writeToExcelCellQA(int row, int cell, String data) throws IOException {
        MainLibrary  obj = new MainLibrary (driver);
        XSSFCell cell1;
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(obj.loadQA_Properties("excelPath"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fi);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("TestCases");
        cell1 = sheet.getRow(row).createCell(cell);
        cell1.setCellValue(data);
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(obj.loadQA_Properties("excelPath"));
        workbook.write(fo);
        fo.close();
    }
  public void writeToExcelCellDev(int row, int cell, String data) throws IOException {
        MainLibrary  obj = new MainLibrary (driver);
        XSSFCell cell1;
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(obj.loadDev_Properties("excelPath"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fi);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("TestCases");
        cell1 = sheet.getRow(row).createCell(cell);
        cell1.setCellValue(data);
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(obj.loadDev_Properties("excelPath"));
        workbook.write(fo);
        fo.close();
     }
```

Comment: 1. Create a private method with the code 2. Have all your different named public methods who currently share the same code call that one single private method (Where that previosuly duplicated code now should be).

Answer (score 0):

All that differs between your methods is the environment. If we pull that out of the specific code and pass it into a generic method, we can deduplicate all of this.

**Load Properties**

1. Make a single `loadProperties` method that you pass the environment into as a string (OR you could store the environment as a global var OR read from some other place). For the sake of example, I'm pretending it'll be passed in as a string `myEnv`.
2. `InputStream input = new FileInputStream(“QA-property-file-path-goes-here”);` becomes `InputStream input = new FileInputStream(myEnv + “-property-file-path-goes-here”);`

**Screenshot**

1. Make a single `screenshot` method that you pass the environment into as a string (OR you could store the environment as a global var OR read from some other place). For the sake of example, I'm pretending it'll be passed in as a string `myEnv`.
2. `String path = obj.loadQA_Properties("screenshotPath") + ss_name + ".png";` becomes `String path = obj.loadProperties("screenshotPath", myEnv) + ss_name + ".png";`

**Write to Excel**

1. Make a single `writeToExcel` method that you pass the environment into as a string (OR you could store the environment as a global var OR read from some other place). For the sake of example, I'm pretending it'll be passed in as a string `myEnv`.
2. `FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(obj.loadDev_Properties("excelPath"));` becomes `FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(obj.loadProperties("excelPath", myEnv));`
3. `FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(obj.loadDev_Properties("excelPath"));` becomes `FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(obj.loadProperties("excelPath", myEnv));`

Comment: Appreciate the detailed explanation. I will try this. Thank You! @Mike Collins